# VS2010 extremely slow to close a C++ solution

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a large C project (over 6000 .c source files) in VS2010 Ultimate.  When I close a source file (close editor tab) it takes several seconds to close and the busy mouse icon stays on for another several seconds.  When I close the solution or VS2010, it takes over 5 minutes to completely close VS.  Looking at Process Monitor I see that devenv.exe is doing 1000s of QueryOpen and CreateFile on every .c files against every possible include paths defined and since it fails every time it tries each file several time! My solution includes 150 projects with a total of over 6000 .c source files. This is on a fast PC with lots of RAM and fast SSD.  Run/Build/Debug is fast, it's only when I close the solution.  It's only happening with this solution so it's probably  a setup I did somewhere but what?

Here a sample of Process Monitor output http://grabilla.com/05b08-a36e39fb-cce0-4f1a-8317-3c6d360ef806.html

This is not a show stopper as I can just kill the devenv.exe process but it a real pain!

I googled for hours and tried a bunch of things but nothing worked.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using VS2010? VS2015 is free (unless you're a big business) and much better at handling larger projects now.

Comment: I tried (not really hard) to move to VS2012 awhile back but it caused too many problems.  As we all know, backward compatibility is not MS's thing.  I haven't tried VS2015 but I don't expect it to be a walk in the park.  I tried moving VS2012 MVC apps to VS2015 and that too is not a walk in the park.

Comment: If the VS2010 is trying every possible path to find the specific file, for saving,  That is a very strong indication that the project is not setup correctly.   You might want to 1) only enable one project at a time  2) be sure the project has a root path set up.  3) be sure each individual file has the correct path set.

Comment: 1) not sure about this because all projects are required for the whole thing to run.  2) where do you set that? 3)I don't understand.  How do set the individual file path when all the files show properly in solution explorer?

Comment: Anybody with a clue?